# Error on Silverlight WCF access via https

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight-4.0, ssl, https

From my silverlight 4.0 application. I can access the WCF File easily but when moved to https, I can't access the WCF Service. The error details are following:

```
An unknown error occurred. Please contact your system Administrator for more information.

An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.

  at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
  at FileSearch.SearchServices.GetTypeofFileDetailedCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
  at FileSearch.Home.<SearchButton_Click>b__0(Object s, GetTypeofFileDetailedCompletedEventArgs ea)
  at FileSearch.SearchServices.SearchServiceClient.OnGetTypeofFileDetailedCompleted(Object state)
```

I have seen different posts regarding this issue, but nothing is pointing me in a proper direction.

Here are the details regarding my web.config file for the web application that hosts the silverlight application as well as the WCF Service.

```
<services>
  <service name="FileSearch.Web.Services.SearchService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="FileSearch.Web.Services.SearchService.customBinding0" contract="FileSearch.Web.Services.SearchService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

and here is the servicerefernce.clientconfig file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_SearchService">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="../Services/SearchService.svc"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_SearchService"
                contract="SearchServices.SearchService" name="CustomBinding_SearchService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE:**

I've received answers to run the service in the https mode only. I want to run the service in both http and https modes.

any ideas regarding this ?

Comment: Can you post the code for the operation you are trying to call in the service?  It sounds like there was an exception in that operation.

Comment: but it is working fine on `http`. The issue is with `https`

Comment: You don't have any security settings in your config file on the binding - that might be part of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify two endpoints one with secured transport and one without it.

Comment: That is correct. It worked. Furthermore, I had to update the service reference that resulted in two endpoints and two bindings in the clientconfig file and then dynamically accessing the binding by its name on the basis of `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Scheme.StartsWith("https")` did it all... (for anyone coming later to view this)

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
<security mode="Transport" />
```

in you service config file. this should be nested inside the binding node.

Check out the security mode configuration section in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197941%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) article.

Comment: Do you mean adding `<security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"></security>` to this? because there is no straightforward `mode` attribute under security...

Answer (score 0):

For supporting Https scheme, you'd need to change transport to `<httpsTransport>.` I see you're using `<httpTransport>.`

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I tried Vinay's method with `binding=wsHttpBinding` and it worked, but it only worked for https mode. I want it running for both http and https modes...